# KEYCLOAK Test Connection doesn't work "Error! Failed to send email"

Tags: ssl, smtp, keycloak

I am trying to use the Forgot Password function for my Keycloak authentication. So I have already set On for the Forgot Password in the Login section. And I have tried to set up the configurations under Realm Email.
  In the email tab I entered

```
host  smtp.gmail.com
smtp port 465 
username  ***@gmail.com 
SSL  enabled 
Authentication - enabled with username and password
```

But when i'm testing the connection, I keep getting the error "Error! Failed to send email".

Any Help would be highly appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You need to provide your email address to Keycloak administrator's email address, and turn on "Allow less secure apps" on Google account settings page.
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

If succeed, you can see SMTP test message from Keycloak in your mail box.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already tried that but it didn't work until i disabled my antivirus

Comment: but it only to 30 may 2022.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have used the wrong port with enabling SSL

```
If SSL is enabled      ---> port should be  456

If StartTLS is enabled ---> port should be  587
```